# Laravel API - JSONP response returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, json, ajax, api, laravel

I am working on a Laravel API. My web application is making a `GET` request to my API. But because the API is set to a subdomain (`http://api.geladaris.dev/v1/books`), I have to use `JSONP` to make Cross-Origin `GET` requests work to this endpoint.

On the client side I have a [`polymer` element](http://coderfin.github.io/byutv-jsonp/components/byutv-jsonp/), that generates the `GET` request and the server should return a `jsonp` response by Laravel.

The Laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#json-responses) states, that the `setCallback` method is to be chained to the response like this:

```
 return response()
        ->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA'])
        ->setCallback($request->input('callback'));
```

And that is what my `index` method on my `Api\BooksController` looks like:

```
public function index()
{
    return response()
        ->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA'])
        ->setCallback($request->input('callback'));
}
```

And my `Routes.php`

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'api.geladaris.dev'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
        Route::resource('books', 'Api\BooksController');
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, all I get is a `500 Internal Server Error`, when the request is generated and the server returns above code, with the "setCallback" method:

[image: 500 Internal Server Error]

This only happens, if I use the `setCallback` Method. If I omit it, and return a normal `json` response instead of `jsonp`, the file is found, but I don't get the `parseResponse` I get, when accessing another API, f.e. http://api.github.com/users or http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. Notice the very first line:

[image: parseResponse in front of json]

I am not sure how to proceed from here on. I have disabled the `CSRF` Middleware and run my routes without any Middleware.

I also tried using the `api` middleware, witout any positive results.

My next aproach would be to install a `CORS` library and try setting the right response headers, but I doubt that the problem will be found there, since I checked and compared the headers from three different API's (Google News, Github, Json Placeholder) to my API and the only substantial difference I found, was the missing `parseResponse` before the actual returned JSON.

Therefore I wonder: How do I set the `JSONP` response in Laravel to be found and not return 500 Server error?

---

Since the error indicates a Server Error, here some details to the server:

I am using WAMP.

My `vhost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/geladaris/public"
    ServerName geladaris.dev
    ServerAlias *.geladaris.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

My `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       geladaris.dev
127.0.0.1       api.geladaris.dev
```

Comment: You should probably look in your server's error log. Also, you can easily configure CORS as an alternative to JSONP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that

```
return response()
    ->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA'])
    ->setCallback($request->input('callback'));
```

Just required the Request to be put through the index method like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
return response()
    ->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA'])
    ->setCallback($request->input('callback'));
}
```